# Applying proxy to an object

Tags: javascript

**Hi, I am trying to transform an object into a proxy, without changing the reference to the object:**

Here is a simple class:

```
class Foo {
  constructor () {
    this.a = 'bar'
  }
}
const foo = new Foo()
```

Here is my Proxy:

```
const proxy = new Proxy(foo, {
  get () {
    return 'proxy-bar'
  },
  set () {
    // Don't do anything
    return true
  }
})
```

Here is what a normal use of this proxy does:

```
console.log(foo.a) // bar
console.log(proxy.a) // proxy-bar
```

**Now, I want to keep using `foo`, but with the capabilities of `proxy`. So I tried to use `Object.assign` which seems to work only for the getter, but not for the setter. Is their something I miss?**

```
Object.assign(foo, proxy)
console.log(foo.a) // Getter works: proxy-bar

foo.a = 'proxy-proxy-bar'
console.log(foo.a) // Setter does not work: proxy-proxy-bar
```

Comment: "*transform an object into a proxy, without changing the reference to the object*" - that is simply not possible. You need to create `foo` as a proxy in the first place, there's no way around that.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52031628/transform-a-javascript-object-into-a-proxy-and-not-its-reference

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the proxy in your constructor and return it :

```
class Foo {
  constructor() {
    this.a = 'bar';
    return new Proxy(this, {
      get() {
        return 'proxy-bar'
      },
      set() {
        // Don't do anything
        return true
      }
    });
  }
}


const foo = new Foo();
foo.a = 'proxy-proxy-bar';
console.log(foo.a); // proxy-bar
```